# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función durante un tiempo determinado?

Tags: java, time

Primero, un poco de contexto, estoy implementando un programa para realizar mediciones biológicas por medio de un sensor, este sensor tiene una frecuencia de muestreo variable, por ende requiero poder controlar el tiempo en que éste está adquiriendo datos. Entonces, requiero poder ejecutar una linea de código (Sysytem.in.read()) durante 5 segundos y que luego de esto prosiga con las demás lineas de código.

Me llegaron recomendaciones de utilizar TIMER y configuraciones mediante HILOS, pero desconozco su implementacion y heme aquí buscando respuestas...

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 2):

Primero instancias el Timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Luego creas la tarea de ejecución

```
TimerTask Ejecuta = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        ///Aqui tu codigo
    }
};
```

//Ahora inicias el timer en este caso la tarea se ejecutará cada hora

```
timer.schedule(Ejecuta , 1, 1000*60*60);
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero no necesito que se ejecute más de una vez, solo necesito que lo haga una vez durante 5 segundos y prosiga con el resto del código. Que debería cambiar del código que pusiste?

Muchísimas gracias por responder!

Comment: Solo quieres que el código se detenga por un tiempo? en ese caso usa el `Thread.sleep(5000);` con este código la ejecución se detendrá por 5 segundos

Comment: Al revés, quiero que funcione durante 5 segundos y se detenga. System.in.read funciona abriendo la entrada serial de datos indefinidamente, generandome conflictos, requiero que solo adquiera datos durante 5 segundos.